# loops and conditionals inside triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have this piece of logic I would like to implement as a trigger, but I have no idea how to do it! I want to create a trigger that, when a row is deleted, it checks to see if the value of one of its columns exists in another table, and if it does, it should also perform a delete on another table based on another column.

So say we had a table Foo that has columns Bar, Baz. This is what id be doing if i did not use a trigger:

```
function deleteFromFooTable(FooId)
{
  SELECT (Bar,Baz) FROM FooTable WHERE id=FooId
  if not-empty(SELECT * FROM BazTable WHERE id=BazId)
    DELETE FROM BarTable WHERE id=BarId

  DELETE FROM FooTable WHERE id=FooId

}
```

I jumped some hoops in that pseudo code, but i hope you all get where im going. It seems what i would need is a way to do conditionals and to loop(in case of multiple row deletes?) in the trigger statement. So far, I haven't been able to find anything. Is this not possible, or is this bad practice? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have Foreign Key relationships setup between these tables, you need to do that. I will show you the command for setting up what you want when you create the table. Clearly, you will just need to update the table.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id INT, bar_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (bar_id) REFERENCES bar(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

This will delete any "orphans" when a Foo record is deleted.

Comment: thanks kevin, this almost does what i need, except whether or not i delete it depends on whether it is referenced by another table. How would i do that?

Comment: @Ying That is what this should do. It will only delete something if it is not referenced by another table.